# Dropbox link shows code of my PHP file instead of executing it

Tags: php, backend, dropbox

I have a PHP file for my back-end side of project and I upload it inside of my Dropbox. and the problem is when I copy the link of that file inside my browser, it shows the code of the file instead of run it. I tried to change the link to `dl.dropboxusercontent/` as some similar problems suggest that but same thing happen.
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: PHP is executed by the server, not by the browser, so you need to host it on a server capable of executing PHP

Comment: Dropbox isn't a PHP server, it's just a filesystem

Comment: As mentioned in the other comments you will end up with simply opening the PHP file as an ordinary textfile. Even if Dropbox is "a server" it won't execute the PHP file for you. You need to place the PHP file on a server that can execute the file, and provide the result as web pages. You can set up such an server locally, or use any web hosting services available on internet.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What makes you think that Dropbox can "execute" the PHP file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access the file directly. PHP code needs to be compiled. If you are using Windows WAMP device, you will run the server and log in via http Unlike PHP, running HTML is directly on the browser so you see your HTML "code"

see: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-your-own-wampserver/